# Django: Why does this test fail?

Tags: django, django-tests

I an new to Django and to Test Driven Devolopment as well.

After working through the tutorials in the 1.11 official documentation
I am starting my first app:  wos_2017_2

This test fails and I cannot figure out why:

```
import unittest
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test import Client
from .models import *
from .views import *
class SimpleTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_index(self):
        client = Client()
        response = client.get('/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

FAIL: test_index (wos_2017_2.tests.SimpleTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/js/django/wos/wos_2017_2/tests.py", line 16, in test_index
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 404 != 200
```

This link in the browser works without a problem:

```
http://localhost:8000/wos_2017_2/
```

In the shell (run from the project root):

```
>>> from django.test import Client
>>> client = Client()
>>> response = client.get('/')
>>> response = client.get('wos_2017_2/index')
Not Found: /wos_2017_2index
>>> response = client.get('wos_2017_2/')
Not Found: /wos_2017_2
>>> response = client.get('/wos_2017_2/')
>>> response = client.get('/wos_2017_2/index/')
Not Found: /wos_2017_2/index/
>>> response = client.get('/wos_2017_2/')
>>> response.status_code
200
```

in wos_2017_1.urls.py:

```
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import url    
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),   
]
```

Comment: Could you post the view of the url mentioned above?

Comment: the url you tested may be http://localhost:8000/

Comment: Please show your project's `urls.py` (the one in the same directory as your `settings.py`.

Comment: @rajkris the url is on the local host.  While running the test, the server was not running.  I ran ./manage test

Comment: @Alasdair The project urls.py:    
from django.conf.urls import url, include  
from django.contrib import admin  

urlpatterns = [  
    url(r'^wos_2017_2/', include('wos_2017_2.urls')),  
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),  ]

Comment: @Hayden: yes it was at localhost:8000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`client.get('/')` is failing because you haven't defined a URL pattern for `^$` in your root url config (the one in the same directory as your `settings.py`).

You have included your urls with:

```
url(r'^wos_2017_2/', include('wos_2017_2.urls')),
```

and in that urls you have

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
```

Therefore in your test you should use `response = client.get('/wos_2017_2/')`